# Add fields in related list on UI

Tags: page-layout, related-list

I have 3 objects (A, B, C). B have master-detail relationship to object A(master). Also object B have lookup on object C(parent). On layout of object A I have related list of records of object B. I need to show some fields from object C on this related list as if I have them on object B. What is the best way to show them? (I can't change relatioship between B and C to Master-Detail)

Comment: I think the best way is to change the type from lookup to master-detail relationship on your C object. Then you will have the fields accessible from the related list.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I know, but I can't change this relationship(

Comment: See if this helps : http://salesforcetechstuff.blogspot.in/2010/09/combine-related-list-of-same-object-to.html

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have one related list that has two sources. Try something like VF Component/ VF Page.

Comment: FYI : It's in Salesforce Idea Forume : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqNCAA0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is to go for formula fields.

If you need to display some fields in A from C, then create a pair of formula fields in B object such as `C__r.My_Field__c` and add them in A's related list, that way if you ever need to change the fields you want to display, it's just editing a quick formula field.

Comment: thanks for you answer Javier, but I need display these fields(obect C fields) in related list area of object B(these values connected to object B)

Comment: @I.Kliavakin I expressed myself wrong, let me edit. Nonetheless, it isn't a problem: you add the formula fields in B and edit the related list in A to show B's formula fields that represent C's fields. Does it make sense to you?